# MYSQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP not converting

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to pull data from my DB and have it organized by `DATE` by using the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` but it just seems to not work properly. This is just one of my failed attempts. the issue that I am encountering is that I am trying to convert a `Field` in my table to a UnixTimeStamp, but it doesn't seem to work. the purpose of this query is to pull all future birthdays, and if the birthday has passed, we give it a '0' value in the `hasItPassed` column, if not, we give it a '1' value. the way I am trying to organize this table is have all upcoming birthdays listed (have the closest birthday at the top) and have all birthdays that have passed at the bottom of the list.

`(EXAMPLE) bDay.date format --> '10/07/2013'`

So my question is, does anyone know the best way to convert a date field in your DB to a unixTime format?? what happens in this example is in my field `hasItPassed`, everything gets turned into `0` when in fact some of the dates haven't passed(so some should have a `1` instead of a `0`). Therefore I know I'm having issues with the conversion.

```
SELECT bDay.id, bDay.userid, bDay.summary,
bDay.time_create, bDay.Address, bDay.date, bDay.time, 
CASE WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bDay.date) >= NOW( ) 
THEN  '1'
ELSE  '0'
END AS hasItPassed
FROM 
BirthdayTable
WHERE
ORDER BY hasItPassed DESC , 
CASE WHEN hasItPassed =1
THEN date
END ASC , 
CASE WHEN hasItPassed =0
THEN date
END DESC
```

If there is any confusion, please let me know and I will reformat the question. thank yall!!!

Comment: Why do you care about UNIX timestamps? If you have date fields already, this is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make your comparison compare dates or timestamps - you have it mixed up.
e.g.

```
bDay.date >= date(NOW())
```

or

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(bDay.date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: I just tried it, and still no lunch, what does work is if I make the comparison look like this ---> ` bDay.date >= '10/07/2013' ` like that works exactly how i want it, but I know its not the proper way of fixing this issue. Any other ideas on how to fix it? I do appreciate your answer though!

Comment: is bDay.date a DATE column? What you suggest isn't a valid way of comparing dates, you should use a ISO8601 style of yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: As an aside, when debugging this kind of thing, it's helpful to add parts of an expression to the query output to see where it might be going wrong, e.g. select bDay.date, unix_timestamp(bDay.date), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(bDay.date)) ....

Comment: ok i gotcha! Im going to get started on that now. I'll comment if I run into else. thank you!